# Javascript event handler won't change another element's event handler

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling, dom-events

I have two divs, div1 and div2. When div2 is clicked, I want to change the "onmouseover" handler for div1. Here is fiddle code (https://jsfiddle.net/au43obnz/2/):

```
<div id='div1'
onmouseover='this.style.color=`purple`'
onmouseout='this.style.color=`black`'
onclick='this.onmouseover=null; this.onmouseout = null;'>
hello
</div>

<br>

<div id='div2'
onclick="div1 = document.getElementById(`div1`); div1.style.color=`blue`; div1.onmouseover = 'this.style.color=`yellow`';">
world
</div>
```

div2's onclick handler is working when I try to change another element of div1 (e.g. `div1.style.color='blue'`), and div1's onclick handler is successfully changing the onmouseover function for itself (e.g. `onclick='this.onmouseover=null; this.onmouseout = null;`).

But **the div2 onclick handler won't change the onmouseover function for div1**. I've tried changing `div1.onmouseover = "this.style.color='yellow'"` to `div1.onmouseover = "document.getElementById('div1').style.color='yellow'"`, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `element.onmouseover` is supposed to be set to a function not a string, replace `div1.onmouseover = 'this.style.color=\`yellow\`';` with `div1.onmouseover = function() { this.style.color='yellow'; }` and this should work.

Comment: @Titus thank you that did work! why does it work, then, to specify `onmouseover='this.style.color="purple"'` within div1? (Also, if you put this as an answer, I'll choose it!)

Comment: Because the HTML attribute is parsed as a string. It gets turned into a function that executes that JavaScript.

Comment: If you used `setAttribute("onmouseover", ...)` it would work like the HTML attribute.

Comment: Because unlike setting the event listener using a HTML element attribute `<div onmouseover="..." />` where you can use just a string. In JavaScript, setting an event listener (a DOM element's property) is done using functions. You can get a better understanding by going through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: thanks yall, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

A control variable can be used to drive the program. In this way, the necessary conditions for directing the program are checked. In the solution below, the old `mouseover` event of the first `<div>` element is fired unless the second `<div>` is clicked; After clicking the second `<div>`, the new `mouseover` event of the first `<div>` is fired.

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
let passive = false, newEventHandler = false;

/* old mouse over event */
div1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if(!passive && !newEventHandler) {
    this.style.color = "purple";
    console.log("old mouse over");
  }
});

/* new mouse over event */
div1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  if(newEventHandler) {
    this.style.color = "yellow";
    console.log("new mouse over");
  }
});

/* passive mouse out event */
div1.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  if(!passive)
    this.style.color = "black";
});

/* conditions */
div1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  passive = true;
});

/* conditions */
div2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div1.style.color = "blue";
  newEventHandler = true;
});
```

```html
<div id='div1'>hello</div><br>
<div id='div2'>world</div>
```